# How can I find out the reason for Chrome Webstore extension rejection?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, webstore

My Chrome Webstore Extension has been rejected, I think for one of the following reasons:

- It loads a script tag into the background page from an external HTTPS:// location

  - The reason for this is that the functionality could change often/be shared among other extensions.
  - My HTTPS URL is added to content_security_policy in the manifest.json
- It has no comments (the build process removes comments).

These seem like minor issues, but my extension has been rejected twice.

There is no contact section in the developer webstore UI, the generic rejection emails seem automated so Im not sure if I will get a response.

Thanks

Comment: The rejection mail usually has some generic rejection reasons which you can use as a rule of thumb. Otherwise you can send a mail to cws-developer-support at google dot com.

Comment: both are MAJOR issues: 1. inject random code from external source: obviously bad. 2. no comments (change your build process).

Comment: @ZigMandel Remote code injection could potentially be an issue, but I have an SSL certificate so the code is coming a known person, and most popular websites inject code from CDNs, Google Analytics etc. The whole idea of extensions is to extend the page functionality with your own code. Why do they allow you to set the security level in the manifest only to reject your web store submission: they could at least clearly document what will and will not be allowed in the webstore.

Comment: if you know that would at least raise flags, you should have at least taken care of the comment stripping/minifying. imagine you are a cws reviewer, how could you possibly review it without spending 10x time on it? so you reject it.

Comment: also loading a known library (like google analytics) from a known cdn is clearly different than loading random js from your own servers.

Comment: I couldn't find a more detailed reason until I checked my gmail. They provide a more specific reason in the email they send.